# Replace object in a list with object of the same type, but not necessarily equal

Tags: java, data-structures

What is the cleanest way to replace an object in a `List` with an object of the same type, but not necessarily equal. Basically I want the behavior of `Set` when adding objects, but based on the Type and not equality. (EDIT) I also need to retain the insertion order.

I'm not necessarily looking to use `List` any other data structure will suffice. What I need is this behavior:

```
interface A<T> {
  T getData();
}

class B implements A<String> {
  private final String data;

  public B(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }
}

class C implements A<String> {
  private final String data;

  public C(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }
}


Set<A> set = new SomeSet<A>();
set.add(new B("one"));
set.add(new C("two"));
set.add(new C("three"));
```

`Set` should then contain 2 elements, `new B("one")` and `new C("three")`.

Comment: Why do you want a `List` for this?

Comment: I don't necessarily want a `List` any other data structure that works will suffice, I just need something iterable.

Comment: What do you want to do about subclasses? If class `D` extends `C` and you then add a `new D("four")` in your example, should it replace `new C("three")`? Also, all `Collection` objects are iterable; do you need to guarantee the same order for each iteration when the set of members haven't changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will break if you use anything except the overridden add() method to add elements, but it's a quick demonstration.  Ideally you would wrap an ArrayList and only expose one add method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TypeUniqueCollection extends ArrayList<Object> {
  private int classCount = 0;
  private Map<Class<?>, Integer> classesSeenOrder = new HashMap<Class<?>, Integer>();

  @Override
  public boolean add(Object o) {
    Class<?> c = o.getClass();
    Integer index = classesSeenOrder.get(c);
    if (index != null) {
      super.set(index, o);
    }
    else {
      classesSeenOrder.put(c, classCount++);
      super.add(o);
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why compare the hash code? I need to retain the order the items were added, and I'm not looking for object equality, just type equality.

Comment: This is comparing the hashcode of the Types, not the objects themselves.  It's just a convenient way of picking an arbitrary ordering for the types, which the TreeSet requires to do its work.  You did not mention in your question that you also needed to retain the insertion order.

Comment: My bad, theory of mind. I added that to my description. Why compare the hash code when I can just do an object comparison on the Class objects themselves?

Comment: I'm curious about the behavior you are looking for here.  You want insertion order maintained, but you want objects of the same time to replace older ones.  So what happens when I insert an object with the same type as the third element in a 5 element list?  Should it go to the end of the list, or should it go to the third place?

Comment: There is no specified length, the collection should grow as items are added and when an item of the same type is added it should replace any other item (max of 1) that was previously added in whatever slot it was added in.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  You can use this overridden version of ArrayList as your list to achieve what you want.  It doesn't handle deletion.  If you want to support deletion you will have to add some more code to handle that.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I'd really like to keep the space complexity at a minimum. Adding another collection into the mix is something I want to avoid. (This is starting to feel a bit academic)

Comment: The space complexity doesn't change with the added HashMap.  It's still O(n).

Comment: Theoretically perhaps, but we are still allocating extra memory for the `Map` and the pointers to the singleton `Class` objects (4 bytes per reference on a 32 bit JVM) as well as the `Integer` objects we are adding to the map.

Comment: Yes, obviously more memory is used.  How do you expect to do this without using any extra memory?  Remember, this collection is only going to grow as large as the number of different Classes you put in it.  Unless you are generating large numbers of anonymous classes, this can't be more than what, 50?

Comment: True, in practice this heuristic would actually be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I think that a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a good fit for this.  It's ordered like a `List`.  [This constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) will let you pass in a `Comparator`.  You can compare on type and if they're equal, only one will exist in the Set.

Comment: This is good - also, depending on what objects you're adding, you could change the class's hashcode function.

Comment: @sdasdadas in the context of the question, that's not an option.  "an object of the same type, but not necessarily equal"

Comment: I was wrong, I should have said the `equals` function. Wouldn't that be enough to use `instanceof`?

Comment: @sdasdadas There's not enough info to answer that.  I don't know if he wants to compare and kick out classes at the bottom of a hierarchy, or any part of the hierarchy.  But, the `Comparator` gives him the flexibility to do either.

Comment: This is good, but now I'm in the `Comparator` wondering how to retain the order that `List` gave me.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry That's a good question.  I don't have a confident answer for you.  The comparator is its own class.  Perhaps store a `List` in it that is used to determine != 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming O(n) performance isn't an issue for you, perhaps you should extend Vector, like this:

```
public class SetVector extends Vector {
  // override the add() function
  public boolean add(E e) {
     int position = indexOf(e);
     if (position == -1)
       return super.add(e);
     set(position, e);
  }
}
```

Now just instantiate SetVector and I think you'll get the behavior you desire.

Comment: Vector adds overhead for threading I don't care for. Also, `indexOf()` relies on `equals()` which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand your concern about Vector adding overhead because I don't believe it introduces more overhead than other containers.  indexOf() relies on equals(), but you can override equals() also so it exhibits exactly the type of comparison that you desire.  Also, if you don't like Vector, you could apply my general idea to other containers.

Comment: Vector is `synchronized`. Not a huge deal if you're working with a small dataset, but if you aren't sharing the collection across Thread boundaries there's no need for synchronization as it adds a significant performance hit for larger datasets.